# Code Review in Visual Studio 2012, with TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-code-review

Is it possible to enable Code Review in VS2012 with a TFS2010 server?

Our should we upgrade our TFS server to TFS2012 before its possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You need TFS 2012](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Using-Code-Review-to-Improve-Quality) to use Code Reviews:

> This feature is only available when running with VS2012 + TFS 2012. If
>   you connect to a 2010 TFS server with VS 2012 the code review feature
>   should not show up in the team explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to upgrade TFS from 2010 to 2012 in the near future, there is another option.

You may try [Review Assistant](http://www.devart.com/review-assistant/) by Devart - an alternative code review plugin for Visual Studio.

It has functionality similar to the built-in VS 2012 code review feature.
But it **supports integration with TFS 2010** as well as with Git, SVN, and Mercurial.